# Retrieving packet data from web server

Tags: web-services, sockets, rest, jakarta-ee

i need to capture some packet data that are being sent to a particular IP of web-server by a GPRS module. i am using rest web service for the capture of packet data. i'm new to this so pardon the stupidities; my doubt was that can we directly access the packet data to a string using `@GET` annotation to that particular url or should I define a server socket function inside `@GET` annotation and then listen to it?

Answer (score 0):

i think we should provide server socket function inside @GET annotation.
Like;

```
@GET
@Path("/hello/path")
public String hello(@PathParam("path") String val) {
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6608);
Socket socket = null;
socket = phone.accept();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
din = new DataInputStream(in);

}
```